# ReportViewer da error de procesamiento en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, .net, windows-forms, reportviewer, visual-studio-2022

Al intentar generar un reporte en uno de los proyectos de Windows Forms en mi solución de **.NET 4.7.2**, me arroja un error diciendo que la definición del reporte es inválida.

He intentado instalando los siguientes paquetes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las propiedades de mi archivo "Report1.rdlc" tengo:
**Build action:** Content
**Copy to output directory:** Copy if newer (Lo he probado con "copy always" y tampoco funciona)

Ver imagen adjunta del error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del botón que debe generar el reporte:

```
private void btn_reporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from productos", connection);
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     adapter.Fill(table);

     reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
     ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("inventario_dbDataSet1", table);
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
     reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

Comment: Y el reporte está en la raíz ?? probaste con otro reporte? quizás el problema está en el .rdlc y no en el código c#

Comment: @Yussef sí, está en la raíz. Intenté creando un reporte nuevo y el error persiste.